# How to merge .csv files into one .xls file in multiple sheets using Python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, merge

I use the following code for merging data from multiple .csv files into one .xls file. Using this code, all the data are saved in one sheet, but I need to save each file's data in a separate sheet, but in the same file.

Would you help me work out how to do this please?

```
import glob
import csv

csvfiles=glob.glob('*.csv')
wf=csv.writer(open('output.xls', 'wb'))

for files in csvfiles:
    rd=csv.reader(open(files, 'r'))
    rd.next()
    for row in rd:
        wf.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at pandas.  It has very robust [data I/O](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#flat-file) capabilities.  [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) and [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) can both easily accomplish what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into encoding errors so I used the Unicode CSV reader found here https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. This answer is for Python 2. If you need a Python 3 answer let me know.

```
import csv, codecs, cStringIO, glob, os 
import xlsxwriter

class UTF8Recoder:
    """Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8"""
    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")

class UnicodeReader:
    """A CSV reader which will iterate over lines in the CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding."""
    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        f = UTF8Recoder(f, encoding)
        self.reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
    def next(self):
        row = self.reader.next()
        return [unicode(s, "utf-8") for s in row]
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
for csvfile in csvfiles:
    ws = wb.add_worksheet(os.path.split(csvfile)[-1][:30])
    with open(csvfile,'rb') as f:
        ur = UnicodeReader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(ur):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                ws.write(r, c, col)
wb.close()
```

Comment: how can we do the same in python 3 and my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671438/how-to-export-multiple-csv-files-from-directory-to-another-csv-file-sheet    @bernie

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just:

```
workbook = Workbook('../your_path/joined.xlsx')
counter = 0
for csv_file in glob.glob(os.path.join('../your_path/', '*.csv')):
    sheet_name = 'Sheet_' + str(counter)
    counter += 1
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_name)
    with open(csv_file, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                worksheet.write(r, c, col)
workbook.close()
```