# How to export multiple CSV files from Directory to another CSV file sheet

Tags: python

I have multiple files in Directory 
cars.Csv
Bus.Csv

[image]

I have script where it capturing Csv files and loading into New Csv file. But I want to read those files and load into new Csv file .

Sheet 1 : Cars.Csv data

Sheet 2 : Bus.Csv  data

script :

```
import glob, os
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['X'])
os.chdir("H:\Learning\MohanTest")
df['X']=glob.glob("*.csv")
df.to_csv('./files.csv',index = False)
```

Comment: CSV files don't have 'sheets', so there is no way of having two different tables in one CSV file. If your Cars and Bus have the same structure you may put them in one table together, but that's a different thing.

Comment: Csv or Excel I want to read those files and put the data into Excel work book which have sheet 1 and sheet 2